Не запускается программа в Vs Code
Здравствуйте у меня такая проблема, при нажатии f5 у меня не запускается файл и выдает такую ошибку: launch: program 'c:\Users\zahar\OneDrive\Рабочийстол******\build\Debug\outDebug'does not exist. И предлагает открыть папку launch.json. Компилятор у меня установлен(проверял через cmd) и добавлен в PATH.
Вот код этой папки:
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
   {
     "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
     "type": "cppdbg",
     "request": "launch",
     "args": [],
     "stopAtEntry": false,
     "externalConsole": true,
     "cwd": "c:/Users/zahar/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/project c++",
     "program": "c:/Users/zahar/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/project c++/build/Debug/outDebug",
     "MIMode": "gdb",
     "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
     "setupCommands": [
       {
         "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
         "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
         "ignoreFailures": true
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
}


Ну, очевидно же, что такого файла нет. А нет его потому, что при компиляции вашего кода произошла ошибка.  Вот и смотрите эту самую ошибку. Или ошибки.
